# Spring Batch 5 and Cucumber(BDD) integration

Tags: spring-boot, cucumber, spring-batch

We are migrating to Spring batch 5 , and Spring Boot 3.2.2.
As Spring Batch does not create tables , our existing Cucumber(BDD) test cases are failing
Getting the below error :
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Table "BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE" not found; SQL statement

Is we need to create manually the spring batch core tables while firing the Cucumber test cases , or any configuration can be done to create those tables  in cucumber configuration to generate these tables..?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention your stack in much detail. But assuming you are using [`cucumber-spring`](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/tree/main/cucumber-spring) the `@BeforeAll` hook won't work as it fires before Spring starts.

Instead you can use Spring to do this. For example with a event listener in your `src/test/java` folder.

```java
@Component
class PrepareDatabase{

    @EventListener(ContextRefreshedEvent.class)
    public void contextRefreshedEvent() {
        //do sql stuff
    }
}
```

This is comparable to using a tool like Flyway or Liquibase with Spring. So you may want to use that instead of rolling your own (put their dependencies in test scope to keep the out of production)

Or if you need to do things before or after scenarios have a look at [Test execution listeners](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/testing/testcontext-framework/tel-config.html).

To pass those from Cucumber to spring you cn use the `@CucumberContextConfiguration` annotation.

```java
@CucumberContextConfiguration
@TestExecutionListeners(...your test execution listeners)
@SpringBootTest(classes = TestConfig.class)
public class CucumberSpringConfiguration {

}
```

Comment: @CucumberOptions(       
        glue = {"com.db.tax.ust.batch.acquisition.cucumber.steps", "com.db.tax.ust.cucumber.steps", "cucumber.api.spring"},
        tags = "not @wip and not @smoke"
)

@RunWith(CucumberWithSerenity.class)
public class RunCucumberTest {
   
}    how to intilaize the PrepareDatabase bean here..?

Comment: Ah. You're not using Cucumber. You're using Serenity. That works completely different and I've got no idea how.